# costmap plugin question

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does placing plugin definitions under the namespace restrict them to those functions. Even if the parameters are specified in another file but under the same namespaces.  If I use the definitions below it does not complain but ignores  the parameters under the plugin namespaces, if I remove the plugin definitions and comment out the plugin name spaces then it sees the parameters.

```
global_costmap:
       plugins:
        - {name: footprint_layer, type: "costmap_2d::FootprintLayer"}
        - {name: static_map_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
        - {name: obstacle_layer,  type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
        - {name: inflation_layer,   type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}   
      footprint_layer:
          footprint:  []
      obstacle_layer:
               :
               :

local_costmap:
       plugins:
        - {name: footprint_layer, type: "costmap_2d::FootprintLayer"}
        - {name: obstacle_layer,  type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
        - {name: inflation_layer,   type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
      footprint_layer:
          footprint:  []
               :
               :
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204886/costmap-plugin-question/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, they are restricted. One solution is to use  tags to load a common plugin definition yaml file into both namespaces (along with other common parameters) See: https://github.com/husky/husky_navigation/blob/indigo-devel/launch/move_base.launch#L40

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-03-13**:
If I use the above code it does not complain but ignores  the parameters under the plugin namespaces, if I remove the plugin definitions and comment out the plugin name spaces then it sees the parameters.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-03-13**:
I'm not 100% sure on what your issue is, but check your whitespace above. plugin and *layer_ are not aligned. Yaml is whitespace-sensitive.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-03-13**:
yes...the above was cut and past..unaligned  will generate error in yaml.  Any way it seems to work if I just do not define a plugins or layer names spaces. So I am going to close this.